# iconvert does not change encoding, no errors

Tags: bash, encoding, byte

I have a "gzip" byte in my plain text file (I can read it, there is not weird symbol, I cant `cat` or `nano`) that causes an error with a tool in python:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte in line 49
```

My file is actualy encoded in us-ascii, and I want to try to get rid of the error encoding conversion. It should go from us-ascii to utf-8.

Used the command :

```
iconv -f US-ASCII -t UTF-8 id_to_genome_file.tsv -o id_to_genome_file2.tsv
```

without error but checking the file shows it is still in us-ascii:

```
file -i id_to_genome_file2.tsv 
id_to_genome_file2.tsv: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

Hwy isnt the conversion taking effect ? And would the conversiona really solve the issue ?

EDIT: the error wasn't in the file but somewhere else.The errors shown by the tool and its documentation are poorly written. Solved.

Comment: `0x8b` byte is (U+008B,  *Partial Line Forward*) which exceeds (7-bit) `US-ASCII` range. The file isn't `US-ASCII` encoded. Moreover, `US-ASCII` is a proper subset of `UTF-8` so the conversion in question is a dummy/void operation.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156261/unzipping-a-gz-file-without-removing-the-gzipped-file

Comment: @JosefZ Using the commadn `enca id_to_genome_file.tsv -L none` I still get the answer that the file is in 7 bit ASCII. I tried loading the file into libre Office calc to export it in utf8. None of these work. And yes the first input il a compressed fasta fil of genomes but I used zcat to read it, if that was why you posted the link.